# Drawing a tiled map with Monogame

Tags: c#, monogame

I've been trying to implement a function that lets me draw the tiles inside a tiled file (.tmx). I've looked around and found a kind of working piece of code but it [stretches out the tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMDka.png).
This is the code I found and edited a bit:

```
private void DrawLayer(int index, SpriteBatch batch) {
        for (var i = 0; i < Map.Layers[index].Tiles.Count; i++) {
            //Get the identification of the tile
            int gid = Map.Layers[index].Tiles[i].Gid;

            // Empty tile, do nothing
            if (gid == 0) { }
            else {
                int tileFrame = gid - 1 ;
                int column = tileFrame % (tileset.Width / tileWidth);
                int row = tileFrame / (tileset.Height / tileHeight);

                float x = (i % Map.Width) * Map.TileWidth;
                float y = (float)Math.Floor(i / (double)Map.Width) * Map.TileHeight;

                //Put all the data together in a new rectangle
                Rectangle tilesetRec = new Rectangle(tileWidth * column, tileHeight * row, tileWidth, tileHeight);

                //Draw the tile that is within the tilesetRec
                batch.Draw(tileset, new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, tileWidth, tileHeight), tilesetRec, Color.White);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You obviously have incorrect tileWidth and tileHeight then.

Comment: Nope, those are actually correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [MonoGame.Extended](https://github.com/craftworkgames/MonoGame.Extended) library has support for loading and rendering Tiled (.tmx) maps. It's open source so you can check out how it works if you want.

The [layer rendering code](https://github.com/craftworkgames/MonoGame.Extended/blob/master/Source/MonoGame.Extended/Maps/Tiled/TiledTileLayer.cs) supports different map types (orthogonal, isometric), different rendering order (right down, right up, left down, left up) and multiple tilesets so it's not boiled down into a single method like yours.

If you where to extract the relevant bits of code you might end up with something like this:

```
for (var y = 0; y < layerHeight; y++)
{
    for (var x = 0; x < layerWidth; x++)
    {
        var region = tile.Id == 0 ? null : _regions[tile.Id];

        if (region != null)
        {
            var tx = tile.X * _map.TileWidth;
            var ty = tile.Y * _map.TileHeight;
            var sourceRectangle = region.Bounds;
            var destinationRectangle = new Rectangle(tx, ty, region.Width, region.Height);

            _spriteBatch.Draw(region.Texture, destinationRectangle, sourceRectangle, Color.White);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, there's still a few missing bits, like the dictionary of texture regions created when loading the tileset.

```
_regions = new Dictionary<int, TextureRegion2D>();

for (var y = Margin; y < texture.Height - Margin; y += TileHeight + Spacing)
{
    for (var x = Margin; x < texture.Width - Margin; x += TileWidth + Spacing)
    {
        _regions.Add(id, new TextureRegion2D(Texture, x, y, TileWidth, TileHeight));
        id++;
    }
}
```

And the definition of what a texture region actually is.

```
public class TextureRegion2D
{
    public Texture2D Texture { get; protected set; }
    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }
    public int Width { get; private set; }
    public int Height { get; private set; }
    public Rectangle Bounds { get { return new Rectangle(X, Y, Width, Height); } }
}
```

Keep in mind that I've mostly copy and pasted code out of [MonoGame.Extended](https://github.com/craftworkgames/MonoGame.Extended). It won't work exactly as it's written here but I think I've provided enough detail to figure out what all the other variables do if you want to write your own Tiled rendering code.